# Save and uploaded image in Shiny

Tags: shiny

I´m trying to save an uploaded jpg in a Shini app, but I can´t find the way.

I upload and image correctly with Fileinput. No problem there.

I want to be able to save that image in the server to use it in the future.

How can I do this?

Thankls!!!